# Angular ui router tab - hide div when active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

What is the easiest way to show/hide a div outside the tab content when on that specific tab only? My current example shows but I could not make it hide again.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/E6dK5C9ZxVQaicQgfS4w?p=preview

```
  <div class="border" ng-show="aboutTabActive == true">Show me when the "About Tab" is clicked.</div>

  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="about" ng-click="aboutTabActive=true">About</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <div class="container">
      <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a ui-sref="home" ng-click="aboutTabActive=false">Home</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="about" ng-click="aboutTabActive=true">About</a></li>
      </ul>
```